# Guardar en la base de datos Laravel con eloquent y una relacion

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

Lo primero es que soy bastante nuevo en esto, disculpar mi ignorancia.

Quiero hacer una encuesta, tengo 2 tablas:

tabla encuestas

- id
- user_id
- titulo
- categoria_id
- fecha

tabla opciones_encuesta

- id
- nombre
- id_encuestas  ( esta id esta relacionada con la tabla encuestas

Modelo opciones:

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Encuesta extends Model
{
    //quitamos uuuid
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'titulo', 'categoria_id'
    ];


    public function opciones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OpcionesEncuesta::class);
    }
    public function usuario()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function categoria()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::class);
    }

Modelo OpcionesEncuesta:

    class OpcionesEncuesta extends Model
    {
        //
        protected $fillable = [
            'nombre'
        ];
    
        public function encuesta()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Encuesta::class);
        }
    }
```

La informacion en la tabla encuestas la guarda bien con este codigo:

```
auth()->user()->encuestas()->create([
        'titulo' => $data['titulo'],
        'categoria_id' => $data['categoria_id']
    ]);
```

El problema viene ahora para guardar las opciones de la encuesta que no se como hacerlo para que guarde la relacion con la tabla encuestas.
¿Como tendria que ser la sintaxis?

Comment: Agrega a la pregunta los modelos y sus relaciones

Comment: Me causa confusión esto: `opciones_encuesta` es una relación de uno a muchos o muchos a muchos?

Comment: Corrigeme si me equivoco pero la relacion deberia ser de muchos a uno, no? Pueden exisitir muchas opciones para una encuesta. Por ejemplo: ¿Cual es tu lenguaje de programacion favorito? Php, phyton, Java, javascript, etc.

Comment: Ok, es solo que la sintaxis me causo conflicto al inicio, entonces edita y agrega la información solicitada, además de la consulta que hayas tratado

Comment: Y ya intentaste algún insert?

Comment: no se como hacerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considera proceder de esta forma:

- Si continúas usando el método `create` para generar nuevos registros, entonces en el modelo `OpcionesEncuesta` agrega en el array de `$fillable` la llave foránea `id_encuestas`

  ```
    class OpcionesEncuesta extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = [
            'nombre', 
            'id_encuestas',
        ];

        public function encuesta()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Encuesta::class);
        }
    }
  ```
- Primero debes obtener el id de la encuesta a la cual le vincularás una nueva opción, aquí lo mas funcional sería el método `findOrFail`

  ```
    $encuestaId = Encuesta::findOrFail($id);
  ```
- Ahora lo que haces, ya que estás trabajando con las relaciones de Eloquent es mas o menos así:

  ```
    $encuestaId->opciones()->create([
        'name' => 'opcion 1',
    ]);
  ```
- O también puedes crear múltiples opciones, con ayuda del método `createMany()`

  ```
    $encuestaId->opciones()->createMany([
        [
            'nombre' => 'opcion 1'
        ],
        [
            'nombre' => 'opcion 2'
        ]
    ]);
  ```

**Referencias**

- [Método `create`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method)
- [Asignación masiva](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)
- [Método `findOrFail`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions)